# What's an easy way to build a level 6'x4' platform over uneven indoor floors?

Tags: flooring, foundation

I recently moved into a guest room that has uneven floors. There is a one degree slant over the entire room and some of the *tiles* are higher and lower than others. I'd like to set up a 6x4 platform over a portion of this room where I do work at my desk, and have just that platform leveled somehow. Other than just setting up some plywood, how would I go about leveling this platform in a simple way *suitable for a few months* (before we hire a contractor to fix the floors/foundation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is small enough that you can simply build a deck out of 2x4 with a 1/2" plywood top (or thicker, depending on flex tolerance). You're essentially building a typical interior wall structure, but smaller.

1. Lay out a simple rectangle with joists at 16" centers (across the short dimension). Fasten it together with 16d nails or 3" gold construction screws. Slightly shorter fasteners could be used for the plywood.
2. Using a 6' level (or a shorter level with a straightedge extension), find the difference from the highest point to the other three corners, and cut legs or simple spacer blocks to level up the platform.

Large felt pads under each corner would make it quieter as you step up and move around.

Comment: Can you give me a link to "spacer blocks" that you have in mind? I originally thought of using some form of cement as spacing material, but would think that something still malleable (non-hardening clay?) after drying would be preferable. If I ever want to move the platform an inch or two in another direction, the spacing at each corner will change, and I'd like to simply reform the malleable material with my hands. Want to prevent any wobble.

Comment: You want a link to a block of wood? You might want to rethink this DIY thing. :P I don't work with clay, but I seriously doubt a gob of it will reliably support 2-400 lbs. of person, furniture, and materials. If you need that sort of reconfigurability, get yourself some screw-adjustable feet with a suitable load rating.

Comment: Ah, it's just any kind of block, not something specific. I'll look into the screw configurable feet. That sounds like what I need. Thanks!